# How to decode URL in APIM policy

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management, apim

I want to decode the query parameters in the URL.
I am passing query parameter value as

```
 "somevalue%"
```

but when i am fetching the value of parameter it is showing like

```
"somevalue%25"
```

I want value as "somevalue%" only.
Currently I am using Replace , but i want some decode method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode` for this:

```
    <trace source="original">
        <message>@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("parm"))</message>
    </trace>
    <trace source="converted">
        <message>@(System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("parm")))</message>
    </trace>
```

In trace you would see a result like:

```
trace (0 ms)
{
    "message": "Expression was successfully evaluated.",
    "expression": "context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault(\"parm\")",
    "value": "somevalue%25"
}
original (0 ms)
"somevalue%25"

trace (3 ms)
{
    "message": "Expression was successfully evaluated.",
    "expression": "System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault(\"parm\"))",
    "value": "somevalue%"
}
converted (0 ms)
"somevalue%"
```